# How to remove these curly brackets?

Tags: list-manipulation

Given that I have the following code:

```
points = N@Solve[{x^2 + 3 x - 1 + y - 1 == 0, 3 x - y^2 + 1 - 1 == 0}, Reals];
{x, y} /. points
```

Which gives me the output:

> {{0.93389, -1.67382}, {0.311843, 0.967227}}

In this case, how can I remove the first curly brackets in order to obtain:

> {0.93389, -1.67382}, {0.311843, 0.967227}

I tried with

```
Row[{x, y} /. points]
```

but I am missing the commas. I need this because I am trying to make a grid, that is why I need the comma.

---

I do not know if it is allowed to ask two questions on the same post, but, is it possible in the above case to switch automatically between NSolve and Solve?

Comment: `Sequence @@ ({x, y} /. points)`? At first, it might not look as if it was what you are looking for, but it becomes clearer when you evaluate `bla[Sequence @@ ({x, y} /. points)]`... You may look up `Apply` in order to learn why it works.

Comment: With respect to the second question: What do you mean by switching automatically? When would you prefer `NSolve` and when `Solve`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I am sorry I did not specify. When the solution involves Root or when it is very complicated, I would prefer NSolve, instead when the solution is simple and can be expressed in "closed form" I would prefer Solve.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher How would I access the elements inside bla? After the evaluation I obtain bla[{0.93389, -1.67382}, {0.311843, 0.967227}]

Comment: `a=bla[{0.93389, -1.67382}, {0.311843, 0.967227}]`, then `a[[1,1]]` is `0.93389` and so on...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Say I have 100 solutions, to access every single one of them, in this way, would be very time consuming and it cannot be generalized to $n$ solutions. Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: Actually, it's not entirely clear to me what you want. What do you mean by "I am trying to make a grid"? Maybe `Partition` and `Grid` is what you are looking for...

Comment: Maybe `Row[{x, y} /. points, ","]`?

Comment: @tomd Yess! I do not know why I missed that. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to the second question: Here is something to start with. Use it in the same way as you would use `Solve`.

```
MySolve[args___] := Module[{sol, threashold, b = True},
  threashold = 100;
  sol = Solve[args];
  Which[
   ! MissingQ[FirstPosition[sol, _Root]],
   Print["NSolve used because of Root expressions."];
   sol = N[sol];
   ,
   LeafCount[sol] > threashold,
   Print["NSolve used because expression was too complicated."];
   sol = NSolve[args];
   ,
   Head[sol] === Solve,
   Print["NSolve used because Solve returned unevaluated expression."];
   sol = NSolve[args];
   ];
  sol
  ]
```

Comment: If `sol` contains a `Root` object you don't need to solve again with `NSolve`, just use `sol = sol//N`

Comment: @BobHanlon Good point.